# npm install failing in azure on jspm step

Tags: azure, npm, jspm

ASP.NET app with prepublish step of "npm install" (in project.json).  This is failing on the Azure deploy due to not having jspm (which should be installed by npm install).  The peer dependencies are also throwing a warning, despite being listed in the package.json.  npm install will work locally.  Below are the Azure deployment logs and my .json file settings.

## project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "jspm install -y", "gulp copy-jspm", "gulp" ]
  }
}
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-aspnetcore-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Angular2 with Asp.net Core starter kit.",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Ryan Langton",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "packages": "wwwroot/jspm_packages"
    },
    "configFile": "wwwroot/config.js",
    "dependencies": {
      "angular2": "npm:angular2@^2.0.0-beta.1",
      "angular2-polyfill": "npm:angular2-polyfill@^0.0.1",
      "es6-shim": "github:es-shims/es6-shim@^0.34.1",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@^0.1.3",
      "zonejs": "npm:zone.js@^0.5.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.13",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "~2.10.0",
    "gulp-watch": "~4.3.5",
    "jspm": "^0.16.24",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.5.10"
  }
}
```

## Azure activity logs

```
....
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\Angular2AspNetCoreStarter\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 85647ms elapsed

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/

Installed:
    206 package(s) to D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\packages
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16202

Executing script 'prepublish' in project.json
angular2-aspnetcore-starter@1.0.0 D:\home\site\repository\Angular2AspNetCoreStarter
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
├── reflect-metadata@0.1.2 
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.6
└── rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0 
npm WARN angular2-aspnetcore-starter@1.0.0 No repository field.

'jspm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The 'prepublish' script failed with status code 1.
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Comment: can you paste the full deployment log? also go to https://{your site}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole, navigate to D:\home\LogFiles\kudu\trace, look for log that contains "_deploy" to see if there is any error inside.

Comment: I was missing some npm packages that I had removed (but build still worked locally because they still existed in node_modules folder).  I fixed this but still get the jspm not recognized as a command error.  I've added the full logs from the latest deploy attempt.

Comment: I believe the issue is due to not having jspm installed globally on the hosted build agent. I have the same issue - see https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/1216